# RichTextBox Horizontal Scrollbar Doesn't Show When Displaying Table

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

I have already changed `Multiline` properties to `true` and `WordWrap` to `false` but it didnt work.

[image]

The code to show the table is :

```
for (int i = -1; i < membershipmat.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                rtf.Append(@"{\trowd");
                ColumnPosition = ColWidth;
                for (int j = 0; j < membershipmat.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    rtf.Append(@"\clwWidth" + ColWidth.ToString() + @"\cellx" + ColumnPosition.ToString());
                    ColumnPosition += ColWidth;
                }

                rtf.Append("{");

                for (int j = 0; j < membershipmat.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (i == -1)
                        rtf.Append(@"{\fs24\f3\b\intbl {\ltrch Cluster " + (j + 1).ToString() + @"}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\sl15\slmult0\cell}");
                    else
                        rtf.Append(@"{\fs22\f3\b0\intbl {\ltrch " + membershipmat.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString() + @"}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\sl15\slmult0\cell}");
                }

                rtf.Append("}");
                rtf.Append(@"{\trowd");
                rtf.Append(@"\row}}");
            }
```

The result looks like this :

[image]

Comment: .NET uses the legacy version of RTB, it doesn't have fantastic support for tables.  First try your RTF in the Wordpad.exe program.  If that pans out then [use the same RTB version](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/194f563c-205f-41a1-9582-4f03fd3a53c2/richtextbox-row-height?forum=winforms).

Comment: @HansPassant thank you so much for commenting. I've tried the solution but it doesnt work when i have too many table columns. Just like when I applied it in wordpad only some columns are shown.